# Unity player controller script is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a game where there is a player, and you can control him once you click on him. if you click on him again you can't control him anymore, but it's not working.

C#:

```cs
{
    private float verticalInput;
    private float horizontalInput;
    private float speed = 20f;
    private Vector3 movement;
    private bool mouseClicked = false;

    // Update is called once per frame.
    void Update() {
        verticalInput Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement = new Vector3(verticalInput, o, -horizontalInput);
        if (mouseClicked) {
            transform. Translate (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown() {
        if (mouseClicked = false) {
            mouseClicked = true;
        } else if (mouseClicked) {
            mouseClicked =false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `OnMouseDown` get triggered?

Comment: Please write code as text.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. 
Please, in order to do a correct question, you should read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and after that edit this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of the if statement is wrong. You forgot to add one more `=`.

Change `if(mouseClicked = false)` to `if(mouseClicked == false)` should work. For your wrong code, `mouseClicked` will never be changed, since `mouseClicked = false` will always be evaluated to `false` in the if condition.

You don't need to write this redundant if-else. Just do this instead:

```cs
mouseClicked = !mouseClicked;
```